# Why can't I access the local variable in closure

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I have the following code. I save some data into the cache variable in the callback of the parallel, but inside the parallel the cache object is always empty. Any ideas?

```
Topics.getTopicsByTids = function(tids, uid, callback) {
    var cache = {};
    function loadTopicInfo(topicData, next) {
        async.parallel({
            privileges: function(next) {
                console.log(cache); // always prints empty object
                if (cache[topicData.cid]) {
                    console.log('CACHE');
                    return next(null, cache[topicData.cid])
                }
                categoryTools.privileges(topicData.cid, uid, next);
            }

        }, function(err, topicInfo) {
            // save privs to cache, doesnt seem to modify 
            //the cache object in the outer scope
            cache[topicData.cid] = topicInfo.privileges;                 

            console.log(cache); // prints out the cached data
            next(null, topicData);
        });
    }

    Topics.getTopicsData(tids, function(err, topics) {
        async.map(topics, loadTopicInfo, callback);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `async.map` it was calling `loadTopicInfo` in parallel for 20 topics. So the cache check was happening before anything was saved in the cache. DUH! Replacing it with async.eachSeries solved the problem.